# jQuery Replacing values in whole column

Tags: jquery, html-table

Once I made i change in one input(x) I would like to refresh values in one table. Each  is made of x*value_of_td_data

Each td looks like below and are generated by foreach for about 20 items

```
    echo '<td id="table_td_value" data-kons_pion="' . $key['kons_pion'] . '">0</td>';
```

with input and value changer i simply use

```
     $( ".input" ).change(function() {
       $('#td_with_value').html($('#input').val()); 
     });
```

but how to make something like that work with the `<td>` which have the same id

Comment: Why don't you add the id to the `<input>` as well?

Comment: id's must be unique.

Comment: its not about input i guess. I have id in input. I struggle to make function that change all values in table not just one coil. If i have 20 items i need 20 functions that will change rows. But i want to change all rows in one function

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `id` to `class` first of all.

```
echo '<td class="table_td_value" data-kons_pion="' . $key['kons_pion'] . '">0</td>';
```

Is `input` an `id` or `class`? You're using both. I'll use class.

```js
$(".input").change(function() {
  var element = $(this);
    $(".table_td_value").each(function(index) {
        $(this).html(element.val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Press ENTER to submit</div>
<input class="input" type="text">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="table_td_value"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="table_td_value"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="table_td_value"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="table_td_value"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="table_td_value"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```